Mix local and sever data in entity Core Data
I have a situation.
I am fetching the data from the server and saving in Core data. That is working fine but my problem is as described, I have made some changes in core data and then I send the changes to the server on button click and that api gives me only success or error, there are few other apis I call, so it takes some time to fetch the new data, but before fetching the data I/user can make changes to the core data but when I get the response from server I override the local data and it also overrides the local changes which didn't send to the server. So, how can I mix the values from the server and the local changes to the model in Core data.
